# How to put div behind marker in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem. Currently when user clicks a marker then infowindow will open and it hides marker. I wish to do so that infowindow will be behind marker and marker is in center of infowindow. Centering is not a problem for me, but how to put infowindow(div) behind marker icon. I have tried with z-index, but currently no result. All help is welcome.